# NaN when joining on Indexes using .join

Tags: pandas

So, I have a left and a right DF. They all have the same columns. But when I try to join on index, using `left.join(right, lsuffix='_CAN', rsuffix='_US')` the right data-set (US) has all Nan Values.

Any help appreciated.

The datasets used:
It is the Kaggle dataset here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube-new  . I have just used the CAD and USA csv's (see Data Explorer on the left-hand side of the page, and CAvideos.csv and USvideos.csv.) I read in those, and now want to join them by index.

Answer (score 0):

No, only 35675 out of 87284 records are `NA`'s. You can check the number of `NA`s by `Series.isna().sum()` (or possibly `.isnull().sum()`) and compare to `len(df)`. You must not draw such conclusion only from observing the head and the tail.

```
ca = pd.read_csv("/mnt/ramdisk/CAvideos.csv")
us = pd.read_csv("/mnt/ramdisk/USvideos.csv")
ca.set_index("video_id", inplace=True)  # I assume this is the intended logic
us.set_index("video_id", inplace=True)

# ca=left, us=right
df = ca.join(us, lsuffix='_CAN', rsuffix='_US')
print(df["description_US"].isna().sum())  # 35675
print(len(df))  # 87284
```

You can also filter out non-NA records:

```
print(df[~df["description_US"].isna()])

                trending_date_CAN  ...                                     description_US
video_id                       ...                                                   
n1WpP7iowLc          17.14.11  ...  Eminem's new track Walk on Water ft. Beyoncé i...
n1WpP7iowLc          17.14.11  ...  Eminem's new track Walk on Water ft. Beyoncé i...
n1WpP7iowLc          17.14.11  ...  Eminem's new track Walk on Water ft. Beyoncé i...
n1WpP7iowLc          17.14.11  ...  Eminem's new track Walk on Water ft. Beyoncé i...
n1WpP7iowLc          17.14.11  ...  Eminem's new track Walk on Water ft. Beyoncé i...
                       ...  ...                                                ...
Gi56dSh8Fq8          18.14.06  ...  It's your good ol' McDonald's Big Mac, but lik...
JGm9Y_hFqNk          18.14.06  ...  First Take's Stephen A. Smith and Max Kellerma...
Fmdb-KmlzD8          18.14.06  ...  The Master Chief returns in Halo Infinite – th...
Fmdb-KmlzD8          18.14.06  ...  The Master Chief returns in Halo Infinite – th...
Fmdb-KmlzD8          18.14.06  ...  The Master Chief returns in Halo Infinite – th...
```

Comment: **Caution**: Repetitive video_id's are present in the merged dataset. I didn't question this part because this is beyond the scope of this question. However, it may make the join completely invalid for analytical purposes. I'd suggest the OP to revise the join logic.

Comment: Yes. It was initially meant to be joined on two indexed columns..including the id's..but I was trying to figure out why certain values were missing. But I am still slightly confused..why are there so many values missing? is it because they are identical on both the CAD and US?

Comment: The missing values were just not present in the original dataset. `us["description"].isna().sum()` gives `570`. Find some `video_id`s from these rows and see if they are indeed the missing records in the merged dataset.